# How to summarize entries in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file `hello.csv` with download times and want to count the downloads per quarter. The code below works well but I become the quarter and the count for this quarter for every row of the csv file. I want to summarize that the count for the quarter only comes once. Or in other words I want to delete the duplicates

```
df = pd.read_csv('hello.csv')
df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.time, freq='Q')
df['count'] = df.groupby('quarter')['quarter'].transform('count')
df = df[['quarter','count']]
```

```
       12.130.14.jga  2016-08-06 23:14:47    34903  0001193125-16-644579   
26955  12.130.14.jga  2016-08-16 01:39:04  1555218  0001193125-12-475878   
26956  12.130.14.jga  2016-08-16 01:42:51  1605607  0001193125-14-323048   
26957  12.130.14.jga  2016-08-18 22:56:56  1001039  0001001039-16-000468   
26958  12.130.14.jga  2016-08-19 01:29:37  1447599  0001193125-15-376713   
26959  12.130.14.jga  2016-08-22 13:09:57  1651308  0001047469-16-009959   
26960  12.130.14.jga  2016-08-25 15:45:39  1271024  0001193125-11-314369   
26965  12.130.14.jga  2016-09-01 19:14:42  1447669  0001157523-16-006477   
26966  12.130.14.jga  2016-09-26 14:06:24   712034  0001193125-12-000769   
26967  12.130.14.jga  2016-09-26 14:07:01   712034  0001193125-12-056675   
26968  12.130.14.jga  2016-09-26 14:07:59   712034  0001193125-12-054758
```

This is an extract of my csv file the dates are all from 2016Q3, so i want to have the output '[2016Q3  11]'. But I become a data frame with 11 identical rows

Comment: can you add an input and expected output dataframe(as text) please

Comment: I think you want `df.groupby('quarter').size()`.

Comment: You might figure it out with the duplicated() function, and otherwise can you clarify the input and output?

Comment: Have you tried... `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='Q)).size()`? (as long as `time` is a datetime jobby...

Comment: I just edit my answer

Comment: don't use `transform('count')` just `.count()`

Comment: When I use this I have the same problem as before, but now I have NaN instead of the counts..

Comment: Any ideas from the others? :/